# How to start the Screen Orientation of the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, orientation, emulation

I want to start the android emulator in landscape mode. It only starts in portrait mode and I want to change that. All I found out is a "-onion-rotation" setting that might have something to do with it but I don't know where to set it.

Can anyone tell me more about this ?

PS: I don't want to change the orientation with a key and I want to have the gui with the many buttons present.

Comment: while creating your AVD just give width as 800 and height as 400

Comment: I did that but then the gui with the buttons is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this probably answers your question?
[GoogleGroup - AndroidBeginners](https://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/0333bce9022ddb0c?pli=1)

Comment: It does most of what you asked (e.g. it explains how to use '-skin HVGA-L') without the need for the 'key' you are on about (lost me completely there, I don't have to press anything, it starts in landscape orientation), but granted it disables the keyboard which was in your original request (so sorry I missed that).

Comment: The link you posted had a link that went on about pressing this or that key to change the orientation which I am not interested in. I can simply change the resolution of the emulator (like using the -skin option) to get to landscape but there is no gui then and that is what I am really interested in.

Comment: I understand. It might help us if you can explain why you want this, or is it simply that you can't be bothered hitting the keys when it starts up in portrait?

Comment: I want it because it gets tedious.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for you to work in emulator in Landscape. but still I cant able to find the view with the buttons. I am only getting the Screen size.

//use this line in Additional Emulator command line option.

```
emulator -skin HVGA-L
```

I am getting error as:

```
[2011-12-23 14:02:18 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: emulator.
[2011-12-23 14:02:18 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-12-23 14:02:18 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

//so I am using only

```
 -skin HVGA-L
```

this works fine for me.

I think you don't need any key for your emulator if you want you can use [Emulator Keyboard Mapping](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#KeyMapping)

refer this for tons of info about [Android Emulator](http://badcodek.springnote.com/pages/2910894.xhtml)

[image]